# Powered down my laptop during a drive partition, any way to save some data?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, shutdown, data-recovery

I was in the process of partitioning my laptop drive which was running the latest version of Ubuntu when I was forced to turn it off, knowing the damage it could cause.

When I turned it on later it booted to a terminal prompt saying `boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found ubuntu`.

I have some data on there that I really want to save before reformatting the drive. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Use a live dvd to boot from, mount the partitions and see what you can salvage.

Comment: Did you JUST change the partitions ?

Comment: You mean like a live disc/usb of Ubuntu to look through the laptop drive? And yes I just changed the partitions.

Comment: Okay Rinzwind I have booted up a live usb and am on an admin account. I can get into the laptop drive but I do not have permission to access the root folder. What can I do now?